# Ansible playbook when condition accessing other playbook but the status was skipping

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I tried using when clause in ansible playbook, however, found out that, it still accessing playbook1.yml, but saw status was skipping. I don't want it to access palybook1.yml at all if value 2 or if value 1 don't access playbook2.yml. How can i able to do that?

```
---
- import_playbook: playbook1.yml
  when: playbook_value == "1"

- import_playbook: playbook2.yml
  when: playbook_value == "2"
```

Comment: That seems rather an odd request.  If the playbook is not run, why do you care that it is accessed?  How do you determine that it was accessed?  Is the access time modified on the file?

Comment: actually in jenkins i got selection like if environment 1 user selected in drop down list, need execute playbook 1 else if environment 2 user selected in drop down list, need execute playback 2

Comment: But if it's being skipped, why do you care that it's being accessed?  And if it is always one or the other, why not just have Jenkins run the right playbook?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use conditions on [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook). It's not a task. Quoting:

> You cannot use this action inside a play.

Comment: actually in jenkins i got selection like if environment 1 user selected in drop down list, need execute playbook 1 else if environment 2 user selected in drop down list, need execute playback 2. is there a way can be achieved via playbook

Comment: No. There is no way to "execute a playbook via playbook".

Comment: i saw this the mention able to import playbook not as a task https://www.toptechskills.com/ansible-tutorials-courses/ansible-include-import-playbooks-tutorial-examples/